Error when executing transaction using Safe SDK
I am trying to do a contract call using Safe SDK and it is working fine with the safe wallets which I have created few weeks ago. However, I have created new safe wallet today and the same contract call is failing with that new safe.
I am getting the following error:
Error in script: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'safeMasterCopyVersion')
    at getSafeContractDeployment (/Users/madhawaranaweera/Documents/Work/poc-rwa/poc-rwa/blockchain/node_modules/@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/src/contracts/safeDeploymentContracts.ts:44:56)
    at getSafeContract (/Users/madhawaranaweera/Documents/Work/poc-rwa/poc-rwa/blockchain/node_modules/@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/src/contracts/safeDeploymentContracts.ts:112:31)
    at ContractManager.init (/Users/madhawaranaweera/Documents/Work/poc-rwa/poc-rwa/blockchain/node_modules/@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/src/managers/contractManager.ts:53:47)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Function.create (/Users/madhawaranaweera/Documents/Work/poc-rwa/poc-rwa/blockchain/node_modules/@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/src/managers/contractManager.ts:29:5)
    at Safe.init (/Users/madhawaranaweera/Documents/Work/poc-rwa/poc-rwa/blockchain/node_modules/@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/src/Safe.ts:128:29)
    at Function.create (/Users/madhawaranaweera/Documents/Work/poc-rwa/poc-rwa/blockchain/node_modules/@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/src/Safe.ts:109:5)
    at main (/Users/madhawaranaweera/Documents/Work/poc-rwa/poc-rwa/blockchain/test-deploy/abby/sepolia-safe/aa.ts:30:19)


Hello Madhawa Hasintha,
Thanks a lot for your question.
@minh-thắng-trần is correct. You are using the deprecated @gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk. Please make sure to use the new @safe-global/protocol-kit.
You can read more about the reason for the rebrand in the History of Safe.
If this answers your question, please indicate it by marking your questions answered. Feel free to ask follow-up questions as a comment.

I think you should make sure all your dependencies, especially @gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk, are up to date, you can also add console.log before the error line to see which value is undefined.
